# Temporary support for exterior wall header when joist are parallel to wall

Tags: load-bearing

I am trying to figure out how to support an exterior basement wall while removing a 5' window header and replacing with a wider 6'door header.  This is a basement with one floor above.  The floor joist in the basement run parallel to the exterior wall in question so there is no way to build a temporary support wall.  I was thing about using floor jacks with a 4x4 inside the cavity to support the top plate above but that won't provide any support to the area over the header area.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Pictures or drawings, including the wall and joist direction, would help tremendously. Feel free to [edit] them in.

Comment: The on the wall joist contradicts the typical house construction. Please clarify by posting a picture on area of your concern.